# Calling a method only after shouldChangeCharactersInRange returns yes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a UITextField with a table below it showing a list of items to select from (similar to drop down list). Now for example when i type 2 in textfield (textfield has Year values), the table would show all strings with 2 as substring. So when i type in 2000, it would only show matching string 2000 in the table.

Now when i finish typing 2000 in the textfield i want to call a method. Everything works fine but i want to call this method only when i finish typing all 4 digits but here the method is called when i try to enter 4th digit.

How can i perform this where i type in 2000 and it will call the method after shouldChangeCharactersInRange return Yes after entering 3rd zero.

Here's my code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
    substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    //if _filteredarray count==1 and substring and _filteredarray object at index 0 matches then call a method here

     return YES;
}
```

Comment: You can search using UISearchBar and implement it's method. It will be easy for you.

Comment: you can count string.length and if it is < 4 dont call the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
     NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
     substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
     if(substring.length == 4)
     {
          [textField resignFirstresponder];
          [self performSelector:@selector(functiontocall)withObject:nil afterDelay:0.8];
     }
     return YES;
}
```

the above code may give u an idea

if u enter fourth letter of 2000, then the keyboard will disappear(if u want u can add it, which will avoid further entering values to textfield), then u can see the third zero for 0.8 seconds and the function u need to call will be called.

Comment: I am currently doing this only, but i want to call method only after typing in 4th digit and shouldChangeCharactersInRange returning YES. Here the method is called before 4th digit is accepted

Comment: i mean when i type fourth digit 0, length would be 4 and so method will be called before shouldChangeCharactersInRange return YES. Although delay is set but still since my method contains code to turn the matched string in table to different color, it is not affected since shouldChangeCharactersInRange has not yet returned YES..